# Parabola plotting tangential to x = const, and y= const

Tags: plotting, simplifying-expressions

```
  ContourPlot[ pm  Sqrt[x - a] + pm Sqrt[y - b] == Sqrt[c], {x, 0, 2 a}, {y, 0,2 b}]
```

plots a parabola, but only a part between points of tangency (a, 0) and (0, b).

pm denotes  + / -

How to Simplify it so that the full curve can be drawn?

How to specify a condition without squaring/simplification to draw it ?

Also can the PlotStyle -> Thick ( not available in ContourPlot Options ) be implemented any other way?

Comment: You can add `ContourStyle->Thick` to get a thicker contour.

Answer (score 1):

You could rationalize the equation.

```
With[{conjugates = 
   pm Sqrt[x - a] + pm2 Sqrt[y - b] == Sqrt[c] /.
    {{pm -> 1}, {pm -> -1}} /. {{pm2 -> 1}, {pm2 -> -1}} /. Equal -> Subtract},
 eqn = 0 == Times @@ Flatten[conjugates] // Expand // PowerExpand
 ];
Block[{a = 2, b = 3, c = 4},
 Print[eqn];
 ContourPlot[Evaluate@eqn, {x, 0, 4 a}, {y, 0, 4 b}]
 ]

(*  0 == 57-6 x+x^2-10 y-2 x y+y^2 *)
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

**Update** -- I'm not exactly sure what you seek for an answer to the question, "How to specify a condition...."

If you mean how to derive the equation without using `Sqrt`, then here's a way:

```
p[x_, y_] := x^2 - 2 x y + y^2 + p4 x + p5 y + p6
sys = {p[a, b + c], p[a + c, b], D[p[a, y], y] /. y -> b + c, 
   D[p[x, b], x] /. x -> a + c};

sol = Solve[sys == 0, {p4, p5, p6}]
(*  {{p4 -> -2 (a - b + c), p5 -> 2 (a - b - c), 
      p6 -> a^2 - 2 a b + b^2 + 2 a c + 2 b c + c^2}}  *)

p[x, y] /. First[sol] /. {a -> 2, b -> 3, c -> 4} // Expand
(*  57 - 6 x + x^2 - 10 y - 2 x y + y^2  *)
```

Or perhaps you want to change the two plus-minus into plusses and minuses instead of rationalizing:

```
Block[{a = 2, b = 3, c = 4},
 ContourPlot[ 
  pm Sqrt[x - a] + pm2 Sqrt[y - b] == Sqrt[c] /.
   {{pm -> 1}, {pm -> -1}} /. {{pm2 -> 1}, {pm2 -> -1}} // Flatten // Evaluate,
  {x, 0, 4 a}, {y, 0, 4 b},
  ContourStyle -> Thick]
 ]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]

One can use `ContourStyle -> Directive[Thick, Blue]` to get the pieces all the same color.

Answer (score 1):

```
f[x_, y_, c_] /; x > 0 && y > 0 := (#.{Sqrt@x, Sqrt@y} < Sqrt[c]) & /@ Tuples[{-1, 1}, 2]

plot[a_, b_, c_] := RegionPlot[Xor @@ f[x - a, y - b, c], {x, 0, 4 a}, {y, 0, 4 b}, 
                               BoundaryStyle -> {Thick, Blue}, PlotStyle -> Transparent, 
                               PlotRange -> {{0, 4 a .9}, {0, 4 b .9}}]

plot[2, 3, 4]
```

[image: Mathematica graphics]